# C read() adds strange characters

Tags: c, posix

I've got such code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char input[100];
    while(1){
        int k = read(0,input,100);
        if(k == 0) break;
        write(1,input,strlen(input));
    }
}
```

And after putting some lines on stdin, like:
example example
example example
...

it it's not normally displayed. Instead, near the ends of input block there are always some strange characters. Could someone explain that?

Comment: you are missing the nulls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`read` reads binary data. It reports the exact number of bytes that it reads. It doesn't do anything other than read these bytes.

C strings don't contain a record of their length. The end of a string is indicated by a zero byte.

So when `read` reports that it read `k` bytes, that's exactly the number of bytes it wrote to `input`. It doesn't add a zero byte, so what you have in `input` is not a string: it's an array of bytes, of which only the first `k` are desired.

To print out those bytes, pass the length of the data to `write`. Since you want to print out the bytes that `read` read, pass the value returned from `read`.

```
int k = read(0,input,100);
if(k <= 0) break;
write(1, input, k);
```

If you want to use those bytes as a string, you need to append a trailing null byte. Note that if the input itself contains null bytes, the first of these will be the end of the string.

```
int k = read(0,input,99);  /*1 less to make room for the null terminator*/
if (k <= 0) break;
input[k] = 0;
fputs(input, stdout);
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no guarantee that the data you read will be nul terminated.  If it isn't, your `write` call will write data beyond the end of what was received, stopping only when it finds the first 0 byte, or when it crashes.

You know that `input` holds `k` bytes of data so

```
write(1,input,strlen(input));
```

should be

```
write(1,input,k);
```

Comment: "no guarantee" is putting it mildly.  read() does not insert null terminators, so there will only be one if there is one in the original data, within the data obtained by this particular call to read() - and there's no guarantee that it will be at the end of the data obtained.